# Label with static text and binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to get a label to show specific text while also being bound to a variable in the VB.Net code. I can make a binding but I cant get it to add the static text.

What I have so far:

```
<Label x:Name="TestLabel" Content="{Binding Path=Row, StringFormat='Row #{0}'}" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                          Height="35" 
                          Margin="203,21,0,0" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                          Width="83" 
                          FontSize="18">
```

with

```vb
Public Class Row
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _Row As Byte
    Public Property Row() As Byte
        Get
            Return _Row
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Byte)
            _Row = value

            OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Row"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
        If Not PropertyChangedEvent Is Nothing Then
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, e)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

and

```vb
Private Rows As New Row

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    TestLabel.DataContext = Rows
    Rows.Row = MyTextBox.Text.HandledStringtoSByte
End Sub
```

The extension code (since I have a custom extension):

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Handles conversion of string variable to Tiny Integer
''' </summary>
''' <param name="s"></param>
''' <param name="I">Returned if conversion fails.</param>
''' <returns>Signed 8bit Integer</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function HandledStringtoSByte(ByRef S As String, Optional I As SByte = 0) As SByte
    Try
        If S = String.Empty Then
            Return I
        Else
            Return SByte.Parse(S)
        End If
    Catch
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        Dim ReturnByte As SByte
        Dim Parsed As Byte
        For Each Character In S.ToCharArray
            If Character = "-" Then
                If S.Substring(0, 1).ToString <> "-" Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
            If Character = "." Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If Byte.TryParse(Character, Parsed) Then
                result = result + Parsed.ToString
            End If
        Next
        If result <> String.Empty Then
            If SByte.TryParse(result, ReturnByte) Then
                Return SByte.Parse(ReturnByte)
            Else
                If Short.Parse(result) > Short.Parse(SByte.MaxValue.ToString) Then
                    Return SByte.MaxValue
                ElseIf Short.Parse(result) < Short.Parse(SByte.MinValue.ToString) Then
                    Return SByte.MinValue
                Else
                    Return SByte.Parse(ReturnByte)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Return I
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

Now I thought that using the stringformat in binding would add the static text and place the bound variable into the {0} spot but all is gives me is the bound variable in the label.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This works on TextBlocks by the way. I didn't think that label content was different than TextBlock text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Binding target is `Content` property which is `Object` type, that is why you cannot use `StringFormat` with binding.

Instead use `ContentStringFormat` property

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Row}"  
       ContentStringFormat="Row #{0}" />
```

Another approach: create readonly property in the ViewModel which will represent value in wanted format

```vb
Private _Row As Byte
Public Property Row() As Byte
    Get
        Return _Row
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Byte)
        _Row = value
        OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Row"))
        OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs("RowText"))
    End Set
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property RowText As String
    Get
        Return String.Format("Row #{0}", Me.Row)
    End Get
End Property
```

Then bind this property to the View

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=RowText}"/>
```

Comment: When trying to use the readonly property method it doesn't work the way it should on mine, it shows $ as an invalid character and without it it just shows "Row #{Me" in the label

Comment: @ARidder101, `Dim text As String = $"Some value {variable}"` is new feature of VB.NET 14, which is same as `String.Format("Some value {0}", variable)` . I updated answer with older syntax

Comment: That worked, guess i don't have the latest VB.NET compiler info. I'll have to look into updating my software if i get the time.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `Binding.StringFormat` is "a string that specifies how to format the binding if it displays the bound value as a string". In practice it seems to work only if the target property is of type `string` - as you pointed out it's working for `TextBlock.Text` (which is of type `string`) and not for `Label.Content` (which is of type `object`). There are several ways to approach this problem, one of them would be to nest a `TextBlock` in the `Content` property:

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Row, StringFormat='Row #{0}'}" />
</Label>
```

This doesn't really introduce any additional complexity to the visual tree since strings are by default presented by `TextBlock`s.

Otherwise you could create your own converter, or you could go with Fabio's solution and utilize `Label.ContentStringFormat` property.

Comment: I don't dislike this answer but Fabio's solution was more what i was looking for. Thanks for the response though, not sure why i didn't think of this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to bind to multiple properties :

- a `MultiBinding`
- an `IMultiValueConverter`

Code:

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Text

Class MainWindow
    Public Shared ReadOnly Text1Property As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text1", GetType(String), GetType(MainWindow), New PropertyMetadata(Nothing))

    Public Property Text1 As String
        Get
            Return DirectCast(GetValue(Text1Property), String)
        End Get
        Set
            SetValue(Text1Property, Value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Text2Property As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text2", GetType(String), GetType(MainWindow), New PropertyMetadata(Nothing))

    Public Property Text2 As String
        Get
            Return DirectCast(GetValue(Text2Property), String)
        End Get
        Set
            SetValue(Text2Property, Value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub MainWindow_OnLoaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Me.Text1 = "text1"
        Me.Text2 = "text2"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Converter:

```
Class MyConverter
    Implements IMultiValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(values As Object(), targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) _
        As Object Implements IMultiValueConverter.Convert

        If values Is Nothing Then
            Return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue
        End If

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder

        If values.Length > 0 Then
            sb.AppendLine(values(0))
        End If

        If values.Length > 1 Then
            sb.AppendLine(values(1))
        End If

        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetTypes As Type(), parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) _
        As Object() Implements IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
End Class
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:Name="Window"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Text1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Text2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <Label>
                <Label.Resources>
                    <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
                </Label.Resources>
                <Label.Content>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="Window" Path="Text1" />
                        <Binding ElementName="Window" Path="Text2" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Label.Content>

            </Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Good to know how to do this but this isn't quite what i was looking to do. Thanks though